# vscode: Configure Tasks Runner missing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed VS Code and I am unable to locate the Configure Tasks Runner to be able to configure the browser to be Chrome instead of Edge.    I am unable to find it in my Command Palette to allow me to add Chrome to tasks.json.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

from dbaeumer "The command is named Task: Configure Task."
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/53363

so I assume you can go ctrl + shift + p then enter configure task to get to tasks now